# How can I bring back the right side of my border?

Tags: html, css

The right side of my 'Autumn outfits' border disappeared and i would like to know how i can get it back?

[image]

```css
h3.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
 
 text-align: center;
 font-family:'Mali', cursive;

}

span.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 4px;
 padding-right: 4px;
 border: 2px solid black; 
 
}

span.date {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Times New Roman";
 font-weight: normal;
 
}
```

```html
<h3 class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">
   <span class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">Autumn outfits<br></span><span class="date">23 September, 2018</span>
  </h3>
```

Comment: Just remove the  **<br>** inside the first span. I don't think you can use that with **<span>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border disappears due to your invalid markup; you can't have a `<br />` tag **inside** of a `<span>` tag, as the `<span>` tag [only allows for](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-span-element) phrasing content.

Simply moving the `<br />` tag to **after** the `<span>` tag will restore the border:

```css
h3.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Mali', cursive;
}

span.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

span.date {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">
  <span class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">Autumn outfits</span>
  <br>
  <span class="date">23 September, 2018</span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a br tag before the end of your first span:

```css
h3.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Mali', cursive;
}

span.outfitsbuttonsheadings {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

span.date {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">
  <span class="outfitsbuttonsheadings">Autumn outfits</span><br><span class="date">23 September, 2018</span>
</h3>
```